# Declaration of functions is not needed in case of the function being written above the main function.Why?

Tags: c, function, pointers, declaration

Writing the body of the function before the main function without declaring runs correctly.But writing the function's body after the main function needs a declaration of the function explicitly.Why?

Comment: The compiler works from top to bottom.  If it finds a call to a function that hasn't been defined or doesn't have a prototype it won't know if you're calling the function correctly.

Comment: One can learn from the past but one cannot foresee the future. That applies to life and a compiler

Comment: ... Was that a bit too philosophical?

Comment: @EdHeal You are now my guru. ;-)

Comment: @EdHeal It was. It also doesn't apply: The whole file exists in the present.

Comment: @delnan - Does the present exist? Takes time for sound/light to reach our organs. When you read a book you do not know the final chapter

Comment: @FiddlingBits - Stop doing that - You may go blind :-)

Answer (score 5):

At the point of reaching the call site, in a textual scan starting from the first, finishing at the last, byte of the compilation unit, the type of any function called must be known. This means that any function defined (this also declares the function) before its call site is fine.

Answer (score 4):

A definition is a declaration.

When you define the function before it is called, you are also declaring it.

At the point where a function is called, a declaration for it should have appeared previously. A definition satisfies this requirement. If the definition appears after it is called, there must be a separate declaration before the call.

Comment: Despite I agree in general you get the opposite result when you pass the `-Wmissing-declarations` argument to your GCC.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the way files are processed by the compiler from top to bottom.

A function becomes known to the compiler when it encounters it, therefore functions whose body is written (aka, defined) above their use in the file are known of the compiler and do not trigger an error, while those defined after their use trigger such an error.

Relying upon the function declaration order is bad practice, however. You should use a header file.

Answer (score 0):

Since, C is a Top down approach. This works on "functional decomposition" concept. So, it takes definition as declaration in 1st case as follows:

```
    void  display()
    {
    printf("hai");
    }
    void main()
    {
    display();
    }
```

But, in second case, while parsing compiler searches for declaration.